# mix-blend-mode hard-light -- How can I use this without removing GRAY from all elements

Tags: html, css, background-blend-mode

I am trying to create an effect of `content` fading into a `header` element.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdesilvio/kthPT/105/

If you look at the result and scroll, you can see the effect I am trying to achieve. If you look closer at the `HTML` and `CSS` you will see that there should be an `h4` element and a `border`, but since they are set to `color: gray;` they are invisible.

I have tried using other values for `mix-blend-mode` as well as various configurations of `background: linear-gradient(gray 100px, transparent);` Noting has worked.

My current implementation can obviously result in unwanted side-effects, not to mention that I can never use `gray` as a color. How can I get around this issue? Or am I out of luck, if so, are there any alternative methods for achieving this effect?